# python 3.73 (Windows, urllib3) ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

After executing simple code:

```
from urllib3 import ProxyManager

def GET(url):
    http = ProxyManager("https://91.208.39.70:8080")
    response = http.urlopen('GET', url)
    print(response.data)
    return ''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = GET("https://example.com")
    print(result)
```

I have next errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
>       self._prepare_proxy(conn)
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 807, in _prepare_proxy
>       conn.connect()
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 350, in connect
>       ssl_context=context)
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 355, in ssl_wrap_socket
>       return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
>       session=session
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\ssl.py", line 853, in _create
>       self.do_handshake()
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake()
>   ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:/My/Documents/PycharmProjects/proxyTester/proxy.py", line 17, in 
>       result = GET("https://example.com")
>     File "F:/My/Documents/PycharmProjects/proxyTester/proxy.py", line 11, in GET
>       response = http.urlopen('GET', url)
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 451, in urlopen
>       return super(ProxyManager, self).urlopen(method, url, redirect=redirect, **kw)
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 326, in urlopen
>       response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
>       **response_kw)
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
>       **response_kw)
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
>       **response_kw)
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
>       _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
>     File "F:\Run\Lprogr\Phyton\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 399, in increment
>       raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
>   urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)')))

UPDATE: I don't want ignore certificate validation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore certificate validation with urllib3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061640/ignore-certificate-validation-with-urllib3)

Comment: Oh, so I think the problem is that you call the ip instead of the domain's name, and your certificates are probably registered for that domain's name, not for the ip...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

**A. Ignoring SSL verification:**

```
http = ProxyManager("https://91.208.39.70:8080", cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
```

**B. Not ignoring SSL verification:**

I downloaded CA Bundle from [certifi](https://certifi.io/en/latest/), places to any folder, for example: `f:\cert`. And coded like this:

```
http = ProxyManager("https://91.208.39.70:8080", cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs='f:/cert/certs.pem')
```

[Additional info](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#custom-ssl-certificates).

If anybody know another working solutions, please suggest...

Comment: FYI: Per the certifi [docs](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/) you can use `certifi.where()`to get a path to the certs file.

Answer (score 1):

Certificates are registered for a domain's name, not for an ip. Either you make your request on a **domain's name**, or you **ignore the ssl verificitation** (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061640/ignore-certificate-validation-with-urllib3)), or you replace `https` by `http` (will work only if the server allow http connections)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows server 2018/2019 (I tried it on a personal Datacenter Server.) you can issue the command below to allow your programs to connect. This is a system wide fix for what I can tell. I had to run it off of an administrative terminal to get it to work but this command fixed all of my problems.

```
certutil -generateSSTFromWU roots.sst && certutil -addstore -f root roots.sst && del roots.sst
```

Best of luck to you!