# “SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED” error in my python telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

My Telegram bot code was working fine for weeks and I didn't changed anything today suddenly I got [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] error and my bot code no longer working in my PC. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm usng python telegram bot library.

What is wrong and how to fix it?

My error logs :

```
0|main_fil |   File "/home/angel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/jobqueue.py", line 314, in start
0|main_fil |     name="Bot:{}:job_queue".format(self._dispatcher.bot.id))
0|main_fil |   File "/home/angel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 54, in decorator
0|main_fil |     self.get_me()
0|main_fil |   File "<decorator-gen-1>", line 2, in get_me
0|main_fil |   File "/home/angel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 70, in decorator
0|main_fil |     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
0|main_fil |   File "/home/angel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 292, in get_me
0|main_fil |     result = self._request.get(url, timeout=timeout)
0|main_fil |   File "/home/angel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 277, in get
0|main_fil |     result = self._request_wrapper('GET', url, **urlopen_kwargs)
0|main_fil |   File "/home/angel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 231, in _request_wrapper
0|main_fil |     raise NetworkError('urllib3 HTTPError {0}'.format(error))
0|main_fil | telegram.error.NetworkError: urllib3 HTTPError [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)
```

I also tried curl :

```
 curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '{"chat_id": "******", "text": "Test", "disable_notification": true}'  https://api.telegram.org/bot*****************/sendMessage
```

It returns this error

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

In some post they said to downgrade urllib3 to 1.24.1 , i dit it but still same error.
I ran the script with same bot token in local and its running normally

Also this

```
angel@***:/$ python3 -m telegram
python-telegram-bot 12.6.1
certifi 2020.04.05.1
future 0.18.2
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55)  [GCC 8.3.0]
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18062293/2649815

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not an answer, but it can start your bot.

In this file:

> AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py

On line 140-150 you can find something like this

```
    kwargs = dict(
        maxsize=con_pool_size,
        cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
        ca_certs=certifi.where(),
        socket_options=sockopts,
        timeout=urllib3.Timeout(connect=self._connect_timeout, read=read_timeout, total=None),
    )
```

Do this and its will be worked:

```
    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
    kwargs = dict(
        maxsize=con_pool_size,
        cert_reqs='CERT_NONE',
        ca_certs=certifi.where(),
        socket_options=sockopts,
        timeout=urllib3.Timeout(connect=self._connect_timeout, read=read_timeout, total=None),
    )
```

With warnings, but worked =)

Comment: Not working. 

Getting below:
telegram.error.TelegramError: Invalid server response